# Constructing a sequence of nodes

Tags: xquery

Is there an easier way to do this

```
<Elements>
{
    for $i in ("a", "b", "c")
    return <Element name="{$i}"/>
}
</Elements>
```

in xquery?

Comment: I don't understand this question either (see Oliver's answer below). The query you provided us is easy enough and works perfectly for any sequence. Probably, you should give us more details about your actual use case.

Comment: @Shcheklein I was thinking that maybe such query can be written without using FLOWR. Maybe with some kind of one-liner like user457056 showed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use fn:map() is your XQuery processor has XQuery 3.0 support:

fn:map(function($e){ <Element name="{$e}" /> }, $sequence)

Comment: That's interesting. But as far as I can see XQuery 3.0 is only in a preview stage.

Answer (score 2):

I don't really understand your question.  What do you mean by easier?

How about:

```
<Elements>
  <Element name="a" />
  <Element name="b" />
  <Element name="c" />
</Elements>
```

Comment: By easier I mean less code. I was just using abc-sequence as an example. Sequence can contain much more elements.

Answer (score 0):

I also wonder what do you mean by "easier".

Have all items in a variable `$seq` and use:

```
for $i in 1 to count($seq)
 return <Element name="{$seq[$i]}"/>
```

**Here is a whole XQuery program**:

```
   let $seq := 1 to 15
    return
        for $i in 1 to count($seq)
          return <Element name="a{$seq[$i]}"/>
```

**and it produces the correct, wanted result**:

```
<Element name="a1"/>
<Element name="a2"/>
<Element name="a3"/>
<Element name="a4"/>
<Element name="a5"/>
<Element name="a6"/>
<Element name="a7"/>
<Element name="a8"/>
<Element name="a9"/>
<Element name="a10"/>
<Element name="a11"/>
<Element name="a12"/>
<Element name="a13"/>
<Element name="a14"/>
<Element name="a15"/>
```